# Paypal Pro Direct Payment (UK Account )Getting Error Code 10001. Internal Error

Tags: php, paypal

Paypal Pro Direct Payment (UK Account )Getting Error Code 10001. Internal Error

**Api Responce:**

```
Array
(
  [TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d08%2d22T05%3a04%3a47Z
  [CORRELATIONID] => 7c43321ab0811
  [ACK] => Failure
  [VERSION] => 51%2e0
  [BUILD] => 000000
  [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
  [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
  [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
  [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
  [AMT] => 80%2e00
  [CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
)
```

Comment: 10001 is not your fault - PayPal broke. Contact their technical support. That said, something you are doing certainly sent the request of the rails. But while PayPal technical support can look up what happened via that correlation ID, the rest of us on the internet certainly cannot -- how could we possibly help you spot your issue with you not even providing the call you are making?

Comment: Called to paypal support and they did some setting in business account at there end and it works Thanks all.